# Calling base implementation of an accessor inside base class, getting child implementation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set up a series of objects in our code base to be able to provide a nicely formatted string representation using HTML. However, when I attempt to retrieve the notification text for a child class, when it goes to get the parent accessor it retrieves the child class's implementation of `NotificationFormat`, not the base class `NotificationFormat`.

Attempts to clarify by using `this` make no difference, and Resharper suggests removing the redundant qualifier. If I instead change the child classes to use `new` on the methods I'm trying to persist, then when I access the `NotificationText` on the child class which is being treated as the base class, I get only the base class `NotificationText`. I had thought there was no way to access the child implementation of anything from the parent.

My goal is to be able to call `NotificationText` on an object which is may be the base class or the child class. If I call it on an object which is actually a child class, I want to use the child implementation and have it call back to the base implementation for the base class formatting information.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var TestB = new B();
        TestB.Details = "Some Details";
        TestB.Name = "A Name";
        TestB.ID = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(TestB.NotificationText); // works

        var TestA = (A)TestB;
        Console.WriteLine(TestA.NotificationText); // only returns A notification Text
    }
}

public class A
{
    public long? ID {get;set;}

    public virtual string NotificationFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return "<h3>General Details</h3>" + 
                   "<table> " +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Id:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{0}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "</table>";
        }
    }

    public virtual string NotificationText
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(NotificationFormat, ID);
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Details {get;set;}

    // chnage override to new to get it to compile
    public override string NotificationFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return "<h3>Specific Details</h3>" + 
                   "<table> " +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Name:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{0}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Details:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{1}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "</table>";
        }
    }   

    // chnage override to new to get it to compile
    public override string NotificationText
    {
        get
        {
            var baseNotification = base.NotificationText;
            return baseNotification + string.Format(NotificationFormat, Name, Details);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a `private string BaseNotificationFormat`, and then have the `public virtual string NotificationFormat` use that.  Now anywhere else in the base class, you can choose which NotificationFormat you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `NotficationFormat` is `virtual` any call to `Notification` will call the most derived implementation.  When you call `base.NotificationText` in class `B`, the code in `A.NotificationText` makes a virtual call to `NotificaitonFormat` so it will call `B.NotificationFormat`.  It sounds like you do not want `NotificationFormat` to be virtual:

```
public class A
{
    public long? ID {get;set;}

    private string NotificationFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return "<h3>General Details</h3>" + 
                   "<table> " +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Id:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{0}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "</table>";
        }
    }

    public virtual string NotificationText
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(NotificationFormat, ID);
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Details {get;set;}

    private string NotificationFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return "<h3>Specific Details</h3>" + 
                   "<table> " +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Name:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{0}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "<tr>" + 
                   "<td>Details:</td>" + 
                   "<td>{1}</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "</table>";
        }
    }   

    // change override to new to get it to compile
    public override string NotificationText
    {
        get
        {
            var baseNotification = base.NotificationText;
            return baseNotification + string.Format(NotificationFormat, Name, Details);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution. Of course, I worked it out about 30 seconds after submitting the question. Thanks!